# Segues not working after redirect by program

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I trying to redirect from current ViewController to another by code *(after login)*:

```
//redirect to new view
UITableViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuViewController"];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:^{}];
```

The `MenuViewController's` segues are not working after redirected,
but when I set `MenuViewController` as app start page, the segues can work.

The segues just a `UITableViewController`, contains some segues to change between controllers.

Comment: What kind of segue are you using? Any chance you're trying to push a view controller without being contained in a navigation controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at what kind of segue you're trying to use.

"Present Modally", "Present As Popover", "Modal" and "Popover" should work fine.

"Show" and "Push" segues require a NavigationController. If you call `presentViewController:`, you will have to create a new UINavigationController within that hierarchy to use them.

Add a new Navigation Controller to your storyboard, that has MenuViewController as the root view controller and present this navigation controller instead.

[image]